# Hacer que un UserControl se pueda mover dentro de un canvas con eventos del ratón

Tags: c#, wpf

Quisiera que se pueda mover... ¿Cómo se hace si yo pongo un rectángulo?

```
private bool isDragging;
private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, 
System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rec.CaptureMouse();
    isDragging = true;

}

private void Rectangle_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        Point canvPosToWindow = canv.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

        Rectangle r = sender as Rectangle;
        var upperlimit = canvPosToWindow.Y + (r.Height / 2);
        var lowerlimit = canvPosToWindow.Y + canv.ActualHeight - (r.Height / 2);

        var leftlimit = canvPosToWindow.X + (r.Width / 2);
        var rightlimit = canvPosToWindow.X + canv.ActualWidth - (r.Width / 2);

        var absmouseXpos = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        var absmouseYpos = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

        if ((absmouseXpos > leftlimit && absmouseXpos < rightlimit)
            && (absmouseYpos > upperlimit && absmouseYpos < lowerlimit))
        {
            r.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.GetPosition(canv).X - (r.Width / 2));
            r.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.GetPosition(canv).Y - (r.Height / 2));
        }
    }
}
private void Rectangle_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rec.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    isDragging = false;
}
```